# Output tidy html in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

I recently started using Jekyll and have came across an issue in regards to markdown and liquid.

## Problem

When Jekyll compiles the site the markdown data is output in an undesirable fashion, as such:

```
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Title output</h1>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow. </p>
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>

<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>

<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>

<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>

  </article>
</section>
```

I would much prefer a more readable output as follows:

```
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Title output</h1>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatball pancetta shank cow.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

The content of the markdown starts after the H1 and is produced using: `{{content}}`

### Question

Does there exists a setting (or liquid plugin) that will produce the result I desire? (That is, to indent the result of markdown, and remove the unnecessary new lines)